# Inserir imagem no Ireport

Tags: java, ireport

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem no Ireport 3.7.5.
Quando arrasto o campo de Imagem para a pagina e coloco a url estática com o endereço da imagem, funciona, mas quando coloco la no `Image Expression` desse jeito :

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos" + "\\"+$F{FOTO}
```

O código acima gerar o mesmo endereço eu usei na url estática que funciona

Mas dá erro:

> Error filling print... Byte data not found at location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-3.7.5\fotos\clob46: 'ICONE3.png'
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-3.7.5\fotos\clob46: 'ICONE3.png'

**[EDIT 1]**

Meu método ficou assim:

```
public void relatorio ( String codigo ){
      String arquivo = null;

       try{

           conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

            arquivo = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/relatorio/rel_cadastro.jrxml";
            //System.out.println("Caminho do arquivo jrml: "+arquivo);
           JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(arquivo);
       //    InputStream path1 = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.jpg");
           String foto = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos\\ICONE3.png"; 
           InputStream path = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream( foto );


           JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport( design );

           HashMap valores = new HashMap();
           valores.put("CODIGO", codigo );
           valores.put("imagem", path);

           JasperPrint impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,valores,conn);

           JasperViewer jrViewer = new JasperViewer(impressao, false);

           jrViewer.setVisible(true);
           jrViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JasperViewer.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


       }
       catch(JRException e){
           System.out.println("Erro no relatorio: \n"+e.getMessage());
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IReport**

Muda o tipo do campo de Imagem do relatório para `java.io.InputStream.` Cria uma variável de parâmetro  `$P{imagem}` do tipo `InputStream` no IReport.

**JAVA:**

```
InputStream imgPath =  new FileInputStream("C://images//sua_imagem.jpg");

HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
params.put("imagem",imgPath );
```

**Você pode recuperar a sim do seu classpath :**

```
String path  = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos\\ICONE3.png" );
```

**Ou a sim em aplicação Web  :**

```
    HttpServletRequest request;
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
    InputStream path = context.getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.jpg")
```

Se tudo o que você quer, é um InputStream  você pode criar usando `new FileInputStream(path)`, ou `getResourceAsStream()`.

Muda esse trecho:

```
 String foto = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos\\ICONE3.png"; 
 InputStream path = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream( foto );
```

**Para:**

```
 String foto = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos\\ICONE3.png"; 
 InputStream path =  new FileInputStream(foto);
```

Assim deu certo em seu casso porque é uma aplicação `DESKTOP` e a imagem está externa mais com `inputStream` daria certo também:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
params.put("imagem", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos\\ICONE3.png" );
```

**jasper.jrxml**

Experimente isso no *campo que você deseja imprimir* apenas condicionalmente ... No "`*Print When Expression*`" só exibir quando `($P{imagem} != null)`.

Comment: Se você pode editar a resposta pra eu marcar como resolvida

Comment: Editar como ? Posso sim!

Comment: Ao invés de colocar o InputStream, colocar apenas o `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\fotos\\ICONE3.png" )` como você fez

Comment: Coloquei já expliquei porque no seu caso deu certo!!